# SQL Combine Two Tables Next Two Each with Repeating Distinct Values in One

Tags: sql

I'm trying to combine two tables getting all the products available listed next to each distinct user.  So the products would all get repeated for each distinct user.  If 2 users, and 3 products, the table would be 6 rows long.

Table_A

```
select user from users group by user;

user 
u_1
u_2
```

Table_B

```
select product from products group by product;

user 
p_1
p_2
p_3
```

Desired Output

```
user  product
u_1   p_1
u_1   p_2
u_1   p_3
u_2   p_1
u_2   p_2
u_2   p_3
```

here is my code thus far:

```
select a.user, b.product from (select user from users group by user) a
(select product from products group by product) b;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [`cross join`](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php)

( *which conforms to **ANSI-92** standard which is suggested rather than using **ANSI-89** standard which contains comma(s) to seperate the table names in the SQL statements* ):

```
select a.user, b.product 
  from users a
 cross join products b 
 group by a.user, b.product;
```

[***DB-Fiddle Demo***](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7cbbQieZdWY984UvDEtoeA/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a cartesian join like this:

```
SELECT users.user, products.product FROM users, products ORDER BY users.user ASC;
```

It will produce a result of each user and group combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot a comma in your query.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/953f5f/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `users`
(
  user VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `products`
(
  product VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('u_1'), ('u_2');

INSERT INTO `products` VALUES ('p_1'), ('p_2'), ('p_3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM `users`, `products` ORDER BY `user` ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/953f5f/2/0)**:

```
| user | product |
|------|---------|
|  u_1 |     p_1 |
|  u_1 |     p_2 |
|  u_1 |     p_3 |
|  u_2 |     p_1 |
|  u_2 |     p_2 |
|  u_2 |     p_3 |
```